# Java concurrent modification

Tags: java, concurrency

I have the following code:

```
System.out.println(dislist.size());

for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
    System.out.println(k + dislist.get(k).first + dislist.get(k).second);

    if (!dislist.get(k).first.equals(Nodename)) {
        if (dislist.get(k).first.equals(myfirst) ||
            dislist.get(k).first.equals(mysecond) ||
            dislist.get(k).second.equals(myfirst) ||
            dislist.get(k).second.equals(mysecond)) {
                dislist.remove(k);                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Problem is: the print at the beginning clearly says that `dislist.size()` is 10.
However, I get an array out of bounds exception, telling me that the size of the list is no more than 6.
And yes, I DID add new objects to the list a few lines before that.
I guess when the loop starts that has not been finished yet.
Is there a way to force Java (within the same method) to start the loop only when there is really 10 objects in the list?

Comment: If you write 'if (distlist.size() > 10) {' you might be happier. java is no clairvoyant.

Comment: You are getting ConcurrentModificaiton exception or ArrayOutOfBoundException... What error are you getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Iterator<YourClass> iter = dislist.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
     YourClass obj = iter.next();
     if (/* your expression */) {
          iter.remove();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're removing elements from the List as you iterate though it. That's the reason the size is changing.

`dislist.remove(k);`

Create a new list, and add each element you want to remove to it. After your loop is finished, use `disList.removeAll(listOfElementsToRemove)` to remove them all at once.

Comment: Won't both of those will leave you with a `ConcurrentModificationException` when you remove an element during iteration?

Comment: @Mike: that's what they're for. To allow removal and addition of elements *without* throwing that exception.

Comment: @Mike: not if you remove using the Iterator's `remove()` method, which is there precisely to be able to remove during the iteration. Of course, if you call remove() on the list while iterating, you'll get a ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: Well thanks for the answer that does the trick. Will you tell me how I can vote your answer or sth like that? People are pissed off with me because I never do it but the truth is I simply did not find out how.

Comment: The arrow and checkbox at the top-left corner of the answer, but they should go to Adam Sznajder, not me. His solution is superior.

Comment: They went to both, als I had already used yours when I read Aarons